# jquery map from json url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

i have written code to show map marker , but i want to load map marker lat , long value from server url

for eg : http://socialdeal4u.com/test2.php

below is my code

js code:

```
var map;
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = { lat: '39.539429069523', lng: '3.3304989337921' };
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatLng
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'name here'
        });

    }
    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

    function showmap(){
        console.log('hii');
         setTimeout(function(){
            initMap();
        }, 20);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }
```

Html code

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs col-md-12" data-tabs="tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab-red" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" id="htl">Tab 1</a></li>
                            <li class="mpatatta"><a href="#tab-map" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" onclick="showmap();">Map</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-red">
         tab one
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-map">
         <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to get data from server through ajax or post. after that create global variables in which stores your data from server and which are needed in initMap() function

Comment: can u help me in fixing it, i tried $.getJSON( but could not make it work

Comment: let me add some code in answer. might be it will help you

Comment: please comment if there is anything you want me to explain or any part of the code is not running at your end

Answer (score 0):

I have implement this in this way. I have removed additional requirements from my code which you don't want. If anything you want me to explain please comment.
PHP part short code. Use your query to grap lat, long and through loop populate variable.

```
$lat_long = '';
//loop goes here
$lat_long .= "[''," . $result['latitude'] . "," . $result['longitude'] . "]";
$returnArray = array("lat_long" => $lat_long, "result"=> $total_result);
echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

Javascript part where you will recive JSON and save it in global variable "locations".

```
var mapOptions, mapcenter, bounds;
var zoomLevel = 0;
var LatLngList,locations,mapcenter_lat,mapcenter_lng;
var marker;

function initialize() {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    if (locations.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            LatLngList[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(LatLngList[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        zoomLevel = 13;
    }

    mapcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(mapcenter_lat, mapcenter_lng);
    mapOptions = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('home_map'), {
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        center: mapcenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    loadMarkers();
    if (locations.length > 1) {
        mapOptions.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

//------------------------------map----------------------------------------


$.post("php file",{variables}, function(data){

    var result = JSON.parse(data);
        if(result.result != 0){


            LatLngList = new Array();
            locations = eval("["+result.lat_long+"]");
            mapcenter_lat =result.lat;
            mapcenter_lng = result.lng;


            if(!window.google||!window.google.maps){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.id = 'googleMaps';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
            else{initialize();}
       }
});


//Load markers
function loadMarkers(){

    var i;
    var myMarkers = [];
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: mapOptions,
            icon: '/images/Custome Marker Image.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            size: new google.maps.Size(5, 5)
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [JQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99uL0nr5/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap(data) {
    var myLatLng = {
        lat: data.lat,
        lng: data.lon
    };
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatLng
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: data.hotelname
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    $.getJSON("http://socialdeal4u.com/test2.php", initMap);
});
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```